# How can I get IGListKit to space items in a horizontally-scrolling UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, iglistkit

I can't find a way to manage the spacing between items on a horizontally scrolling `UICollectionView` using IGListKit 3.1.1.

I tried different approaches...

#### Using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

I set it like this:

```
collectionLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
collectionLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
```

I also played with the sectionInset, but in vain...

#### Using `ListCollectionViewLayout` & custom adapter

I used `IGListKit`'s `ListCollectionViewLayout` using a custom adapter to implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol, but in vain...

#### What I get

I also end up getting horizontal sections that touch each other (ie a spacing of 0 pt).

Can anyone from IGListKit can help me on this?

The source code for this is available at https://github.com/FlaneurApp/FlaneurOpen/tree/0.3.0 (cf. *CollectionView Demo* in the example app). The class configuring the collection view is here: https://github.com/FlaneurApp/FlaneurOpen/blob/0.3.0/FlaneurOpen/Classes/Custom%20UIView/FlaneurCollectionView.swift

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, solved it using [this](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/issues/498).

In your section controller, override the initialiser as so:

```
override init() {
    super.init() 
    let halfCellSpacing = 10
    self.inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: halfCellSpacing, bottom: 0, right: halfCellSpacing)
}
```